# Multivariate distribution with vectors

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_m$ be mutually independent random variables.

Each $X_i$ in the sequence $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ has the normal distribution $X_i$~$N(\mu,\sigma_1^2)$ and is idnependent random variable and we have each $Y_j$ in the sequence $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m$ has the normal distribution $Y_J$~$N(\mu,\sigma_2^2)$ and is independent random variable for some $\mu \in$R and

$\sigma_1^2>0$ and $\sigma_2^2>0$

$\tilde{X}=n^{-1}(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)$ and we Have $\tilde{Y}=(m)^{-1}(Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_m)$

And $Z:=(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$

A. FIND $E(Z$) AND $VAR(Z)$
I am not sure how to find the variance and expectation of z
So I am not sure I guess $E(Z)=(\mu,\mu)$
$VAR(Z)$ is the covariance matrix $[[\sigma_1^2/n, 0][0,\sigma_2^2/m]]$

B. Find the probability distribution of Z
I think Z would be a normal distribution but I am not sure what the variance and expectation of z is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's write the covariance matrix more neatly as$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n}I_n & O_{n\times m}\\
O_{m\times n} & \frac{\sigma_2^2}{n}I_m
\end{array}\right).$$You're right that $Z$ has the zero-mean univariate Gaussian distribution with this covariance matrix. The most obvious definition of the variance is$$\operatorname{Var}Z=E(Z^2)-E(Z)^2=E\left(\overline{X}^2+\overline{Y}^2\right)=\operatorname{Var}\overline{X}+\operatorname{Var}\overline{Y}=\frac{m\sigma_1^2+n\sigma_2^2}{mn},$$where we have defined $V^2:=V\cdot V$ for vectors.

Comment: So to find $E(Z)$ would you $E((\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$ and then you get $[U*_I_n ,U_*I_m]$

Comment: because I is indentiy matrix